# Errors Loading Image Python 3.6.2, Pygame 1.9.3

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, pygame

I have been following the Pygame tutorial by Meloonatic Melons on youtube (I changed some of the code but it worked for the better until now), and I have run into a problem. I have made 2 extra files to implement called **globals** and **textureLoader**. The error is here:

```
import pygame, sys, time, random
from scripts.textureLoader import *
from scripts.globals import *

pygame.init()

#Important Stuff

#Variables
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 120
tileSize = 32

#Colours
white = (0, 0, 0)
black = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)
orange = (255, 165, 0)

#Fonts
fpsFont = pygame.font.Font("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Verdana.ttf", 20)

#Display

def display():
    global displayHeight, displayWidth, gameDisplay, gameCaption

    displayHeight, displayWidth = 600, 800

    gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((displayWidth, displayHeight),
    pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
    gameCaption = pygame.display.set_caption("Testy RPG")

run = True
while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                Globals.cameraMove = 1
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                Globals.cameraMove = 2
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                Globals.cameraMove = 3
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                Globals.cameraMove = 4
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
           Globals.cameraMove = 0

    #Logic

    # - FPS Counter
    FPSColour = black
    cFPS = int(clock.get_fps())
    if cFPS < 10:
        FPSColour = red
    elif cFPS > 10 and cFPS < 60:
        FPSColour = orange
    else:
        FPSColour = green

    # - Camera
    if Globals.cameraMove == 1:
        Globals.cameraY -= 1
    elif Globals.cameraMove == 2:
        Globals.cameraY += 1
    elif Globals.cameraMove == 3:
        Globals.cameraX -= 1
    elif Globals.cameraMove == 4:
        Globals.cameraX += 1

    # - Player

    #Render Graphics
    gameDisplay.blit(Background.NightSky, (0, 0)) #this is where the error is

    # - Render Tiles
    for x in range(0, 640, tileSize):
        for y in range(0, 480, tileSize):
            gameDisplay.blit(Tiles.Grass, (x + Globals.cameraX, y + 
    Globals.cameraY))

    gameDisplay.blit(fpsFont.render("FPS: " + str(cFPS), True, FPSColour), 
    (0, 0))
    gameDisplay.blit(PlayerFrontBack.PlayerFront, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(120)

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

This is my textureLoader file:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

class Tiles:

    global Size
    Size = 32

    def loadTexture(file, size):
        bitmap = pygame.image.load(file)
        bitmap = pygame.transform.scale(bitmap, (Size, Size))
        surface = pygame.Surface((Size, Size), pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.SRCALPHA)
        surface.blit(bitmap, (0, 0))
        return surface

    Grass = loadTexture("Graphics\\grass.png", Size)
    Stone = loadTexture("Graphics\\stone.png", Size)
    Water = loadTexture("Graphics\\water.png", Size)

class Background:

    global backgroundWidth, backgroundHeight
    backgroundWidth = 800
    backgroundHeight = 600

    def loadBackground(file, size):
        backgroundImg = pygame.image.load(file)
        backgroundImg = pygame.transform.scale(backgroundImg, (backgroundWidth, backgroundHeight))
        backgroundSurf = pygame.Surface((backgroundWidth, backgroundHeight), pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.SRCALPHA)
        backgroundSurf.blit(backgroundImg, (0, 0))
        return backgroundSurf

    NightSky = loadBackground("Graphics\\sky.png", (backgroundWidth, backgroundHeight))

class PlayerFrontBack:

    global playerWidth, playerHeight
    playerWidth = 19
    playerHeight = 55

    def loadPlayerFrontBack(file, size):
        playerImg = pygame.image.load(file)
        playerImg = pygame.transform.scale(playerImg, (playerWidth, playerHeight))
        playerSurf = pygame.Surface((playerWidth, playerHeight), pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.SRCALPHA)
        playerSurf.blit(playerImg, (0, 0))
        return playerSurf

    PlayerFront = loadPlayerFrontBack("Graphics\\manStill.png", (19, 55))

class PlayerLeftRight:

    global playerWidth2
    playerWidth2 = 15

    def loadPlayerLeftRight(file, size):
        playerImg = pygame.image.load(file)
        playerImg = pygame.transform.scale(playerImg, (playerWidth2, playerHeight))
        playerSurf = pygame.Surface((playerWidth2, playerHeight), pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.SRCALPHA)
        playerSurf.blit(playerImg, (0, 0))
        return playerSurf
```

And this is my globals file:

```
class Globals:
    cameraX = 0
    cameraY = 0
    cameraMove = 0
```

The traceback is:

```
"D:\Programming\Python\Python 3.6.2\python.exe" 
D:/Programming/Python/Assets/Projects/Games/rpg.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Programming/Python/Assets/Projects/Games/rpg.py", line 81, in 
<module>
    gameDisplay.blit(Background.NightSky, (0, 0))
NameError: name 'gameDisplay' is not defined
```

Thank you for reviewing my code and wish you the best of luck finding a solution!

Comment: You didn't say what the error is. What's the full error with stack trace? And what debugging have you done?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I have included the traceback now and I have looked through this forum for something on my situation and haven't found anything. As for debugging I have used the PyGame built-in debugger

Comment: The errors pretty clear, read the last line. Where do you declare `gameDisplay`?

Comment: If you want to declare global variables, you need to do this outside the scope of a function. Add the following lines in the top of the file
`displayHeight = None` `displayWidth = None` `gameDisplay = None`
`gameCaption = None`

Comment: @Carcigenicate i defined gameDisplay at the top of my main code but i think the error lies at the display function, i will delete this function but keep the code inside it and it should work, thanks for your help

Comment: @PRMoureu thank you for the response, i will try your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to call `display()` to declare and initialize the global variables in the function.

Your code looks quite strange and there are many things that I would refactor. I recommend to post it on [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: oh ok. i will try code review, thank you for an answer!

Comment: I mean especially the many global variables and the classes which seem to be used only to load and store images. Make sure that the program works correctly before you post it on codereview.